# Open Outlook mail files in iOS app

Tags: c++, ios, outlook, msg

I am working on a POC.
I am interested in build an iOS application that:

- Connects to a NAS (Status OK)
- Create a folder in the app (Status OK)
- Download Outlook files in the following formats: .eml and .msg (Status OK)
- Create UITableView that shows the list of the downloaded files (Status OK)
- Open .eml files in UIWebView (Status OK - Done with MailCore2)
- Open .msg files and display datas (KO)

I've searched a lot and I've seen that the .msg files are stored as OLE compound documents (stuctured storage). The only library found that seems could be useful for my purpose it the POLE that is written in C++.

I have never compiled and used a library written in C++. Could you be so kind to guide me in compiling this library for iOS and integrate it in my project?
Have you got some guides?

Thank you so much for your collaboration